# Could not find a unique URI for this element

Tags: slug

Suddenly, I can't add any entry to a structure.
When I try to save a record, I've got "Could not find a unique URI for this element“. Although, the slug is perfectly valid and unique, but whatever I type in the slug field, same message "Could not find a unique URI for this element". I only got a couple of entries in this structure, so I could not have possibly hit the  'maxSlugIncrement' limit…
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the Uri format for the section?

Comment: The Uri format is "numeros/{numeroDeLaParution}"
The "numeroDeLaParution" is a field from one of the Entry of this Structure.
The strangest thing is everything works fine until a need to edit some data in the already created entries, but then I've got this "Could not find a unique URI for this element" and then I can't record anymore changes, netheir can I create new entries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Uri of each element must be unique but if your Uri format is something that might not render a unique string you'll receive the error you are facing with.

As soon as you include some unique identifier like `{ id }` or `{ slug }` into your sections uri it will work again. Right now you can only save an entry if the field value is unique

Comment: Hi Robin,
Using a unique identifier did the trick.
Thanks for your help.